# Linq left join on nullable field

Tags: c#, linq

In the following example I have entity1, where the user_id is a nullable int, and sometimes its indeed null. Entity2 is something like a bridge to connect entity1 to entity3, via the **user_id**, to get the **person_id** and eventually the corresponding **fullname**.

My goal would be to write a linq query in which if entity1's user_id is null, then don't throw a NullReferenceException, but get null for the fullname property.

Given the entities below, I would expect my query to return this:

- codeOfEntity = "21006.040",  fullname = null
- codeOfEntity = "14006.010",  fullname = "John Smith"
- codeOfEntity = "21006.020", fullname = null
- codeOfEntity = "35716.001",  fullname = "Dave Doe"
- codeOfEntity = "11153.013",  fullname = "Zach White"

**Entities:**

```
class entity1
{
    public int? user_id { get; set; }
    public string codeOfEntity { get; set; }
}

class entity2
{
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public int person_id { get; set; }
}

class entity3
{
    public int person_id { get; set; }
    public string fullname { get; set; }
}
```

**And filled up like:**

```
var listOfEntity1 = new List<entity1>()
{
    new entity1() { user_id = null, codeOfEntity = "21006.040" },
    new entity1() { user_id = 10, codeOfEntity = "14006.010" },
    new entity1() { user_id = null, codeOfEntity = "21006.020" },
    new entity1() { user_id = 1, codeOfEntity = "35716.001"},
    new entity1() { user_id = 4, codeOfEntity = "11153.013" }
};

var listOfEntity2 = new List<entity2>()
{
    new entity2() { user_id = 1, person_id = 100 },
    new entity2() { user_id = 4, person_id = 400 },
    new entity2() { user_id = 10, person_id = 1000 }
};

var listOfEntity3 = new List<entity3>()
{
    new entity3() { person_id = 100, fullname = "John Smith" },
    new entity3() { person_id = 400, fullname = "Dave Doe" },
    new entity3() { person_id = 1000, fullname = "Zach White" }
};
```

**My query that throws a NullReferenceException:**

```
var result = (from e1 in listOfEntity1
              join e2 in listOfEntity2 on e1.user_id equals e2.user_id into e2Group
              from e2 in e2Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join e3 in listOfEntity3 on e2.person_id equals e3.person_id into e3Group
              from e3 in e3Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { e1.codeOfEntity, e3.fullname }).ToList();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use c#6.0's null propagation

```
var result = (from e1 in listOfEntity1
              join e2 in listOfEntity2 on e1.user_id equals e2.user_id into e2Group
              from e2 in e2Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join e3 in listOfEntity3 on e2?.person_id equals e3.person_id into e3Group
              from e3 in e3Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { e1.codeOfEntity, e3?.fullname }).ToList();
```

Notice the simple change in join condition and `select`. Changed `e2.person_id` to `e2?.person_id` in `join` and `e3.fullname` to `e3?.fullname` in `select`.

But, if you are not in a position to use c# 6.0, here is an alternative

```
var result = (from e1 in listOfEntity1
              join e2 in listOfEntity2 on e1.user_id equals e2.user_id into e2Group
              from e2 in e2Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join e3 in listOfEntity3 on (e2==null?-1:e2.person_id) equals e3.person_id into e3Group
              from e3 in e3Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { e1.codeOfEntity, fullname=(e3==null?null:e3.fullname) }).ToList();
```

Comment: Just note that since this is a Linq-to-Objects query, it will work.  But if dealing with queryables, the first wouldn't work at all (since null-propagation operator isn't supported in expressions) and the second may or may not work all query providers. Prior to C#6, the preferred solution would be to provide a default instance as a parameter to `DefaultIfEmpty()`.